I would like to make a Picker in React Native display an item that's no longer in the options
I'm pretty new to react native and can't seem to figure out how to make my Picker actually display the name of an item I'd like to display.
I used https://github.com/react-native-picker/picker since it seemed to be the most "default" picker.
So I did
const [selectedString, setSelectedString] = useState();

<Picker
      selectedValue={selectedString}
      onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setSelectedString(itemValue)}>
      {options}
</Picker>

const options = props.optionStrings.map(option => {
    return <Picker.Item key={option} label={option} value={option} />;});

And that works as intended, of course, but when I add my logic... it just kind of stops.
So basically, I have code that... long story short changes the array of options every time a new item is selected. More specificly, it removes the selected string from the options. Every other part of my logic works (seemingly) except that the selector always displays the first element of the options array.
Now, I realize that the library I'm using possibly does not support a changing set of options. Especially if the item it's supposed to display is not present in it.
So... is there anything I can do with this specific library to achieve the effect I want. Or, could anyone perhaps suggest a different picker library that can do what I need.
Thanks :)
